# Android WebView setCertificate issues SSL problems

Tags: android, ssl, webview, certificate

I have seen a lot of posts and information about SSL errors and I have stumbled upon one myself.

I am trying to access a web page through Android WebView with a GlobalSign CA BE certificate, and I get a not-trusted error.

For most phones, it works fine to handle this, and just tell the handler to proceed.

Some phones, however, end up getting a onReceivedError in the webview-client, telling it that it can't establish contact with the server. This happens after it has gone through the onReceivedSslError and proceeded.

I searched for descriptions and found a lot of descriptions involving HttpClient and either installing your own certificate or just tricking it into accepting all.

However, since I was using WebView I thought I'd make use of WebView.setCertificate(SslCertificate crt) . I searched for discussions of this function, but did not find much/any info.

I got a hold of the certificate that was said to be untrusted, and did this code:

```
try{
     Certificate myCert = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509").
     generateCertificate(this.getResources().
     openRawResource(R.raw.globalsign_ca_be));

     X509Certificate x509 = (X509Certificate) myCert;
     SslCertificate sslCert = new SslCertificate(x509);
     webView.setCertificate(sslCert);

    }
    catch (CertificateException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

With a .cer file containing this:

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----

It completed without exception, but I still got the same behaviour from my webview. First an SSL-error and then an error saying it could not communicate/load the page.

If anyone has some info, has been able to get SSL working properly in WebView, or even just help in ways to debug this. I would greatly appreciate it.

My head is also exploding a bit, because I'm not very experienced in SSL to begin with.

*it's a public key btw, nothing exciting ;)  (GlobalSign CA BE)

some more info:
the ssl exception: 
primary error: 3 
certificate: Issued to: CN=GlobalSign Domain Validation 
CA,O=GlobalSign nv-sa,OU=Domain Validation CA,C=BE;

Issued by: CN=GlobalSign Root CA,OU=Root CA,O=GlobalSign nv-sa,C=BE;

error 3 is , SSL_UNTRUSTED

I do however have a feeling that the setCertificate function, is not to add a trusted certificate for a missing root or similar, but instead to add a client certificate to identify with a server expecting one. Would be good with some more info on this function though, it seems a bit undocumented.

I got the CA through running confied.payex.com:443 through a site called ssltest.net and downloading the cert from there.

Comment: Did you manage to load a web-page with untrusted cert?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to decode the certificate but it does not seem to be valid (actually I tested 2 distinct X509 implementations and both gave me an "incorrect encoding" error).

Can you give more details on the SSL exception?

I did not find much information about the `setCertificate` method. I think this method expects the server certificate. You should ensure that the certificate you decode is the *end entity* certificate and not a CA certificate.

Comment: why on devices (4.0.3, 4.3) it fails, but emulator loads the page as expected? different implementation of WebView (Chromium.so)?

Comment: If you are using InMobi sdk, just update it to latest version and this warning will be fixed. More information here [in Sohan's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32775592/ssl-warning-from-google-play)

Answer (score 1):

The method " setCertificate" is deprecated, so I think that it may not work.I solved a similar problem like yours.If you have your own ssl cacert, you can set networkSecurityConfig .[networkSecurityConfig](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config)  to learn more.

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"


<network-security-config>
<base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <trust-anchors>
        <certificates src="system" overridePins="true" />
    </trust-anchors>
</base-config>
<debug-overrides>
    <trust-anchors>
        <certificates src="system" overridePins="true" />
        <certificates src="user" overridePins="true" />
        <certificates src="@raw/cacert" overridePins="true"></certificates>
    </trust-anchors>
</debug-overrides>
</network-security-config>
```

if you load a url from assets ,you should also set the follow settings.
`webSetting.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using InMobi sdk, just update it to latest version and this warning will be fixed. More information here [in Sohan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32775592/ssl-warning-from-google-play)

[image: Information]

Answer (score -1):

If you have a WebClient which overrides the onReceivedSSLError() function and calls the handler.proceed() API, it can solve the certificate issue of error 3, I tested on Android 4.4 and 6.0.

If you still get an errorCode(-1) in the function onReceivedError(), you need to check the server side implementation sometime, especially when you call the POST method instead of the GET method, because the server may return nothing if there is unexpected POST parameters.

Good luck.